# PDF file doesnt load - Laravel - React.js

Tags: html, reactjs, laravel

I have uploaded PDF file which users be able to download and read .

It downloads but doesn't open

gives error

> Failed to load PDF

Laravel API Response looks like

```
"pdf_link": [
            {
                "download_link": "publications\\May2022\\yFj0H0aOQDBKzcAndio4.pdf",
                "original_name": "2021-Egitim-Degerlendirme-Raporu.pdf"
            }
        ]
```

Frontend

```
<a
 className="edu-btn"
 href={data?.pdf_link[0].download_link}
 download  >
   Download
  <i className="icon-arrow-right-line-right"></i>
</a>
```